# Mixing tab numbers

Tags: javascript, imacros

I got small problem with my script. I spend five hours on this, but I don't know how can I repair my code.

I have problem with tabs indexes. So I opening new tabs inside javascript loop and setting url goto command for execute url from file.

Unfortunately, a blank page about blank appears unfortunately. In addition, the TAB T = n command stops working. Three cards are open and the TAB T = 3 command does not go to this card. How to fix it?

```
var closeTabs = "CODE:";
closeTabs += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + "\n";
iimPlay(closeTabs);
for (id = 1; id <= 1; id++) {
var load =  "CODE:";
load += "SET !DATASOURCE C:\\Users\\WWW\\Desktop\\xxx\\accounts.txt" + "\n";
load += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n";
load += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE "+id+"" + "\n";
load += "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n";
load += "SET !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}" + "\n";
iimPlay(load);
var account = iimGetLastExtract(0);
var setUrl = "CODE:";
setUrl += "TAB T=1" + "\n";
setUrl += "URL GOTO="+account+"" + "\n";
setUrl += "WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n";
iimPlay(setUrl);
   for(link = 1; link <= 3; link++) {
      var ytSource = "CODE:";
      ytSource += "SET !DATASOURCE C:\\Users\\WWW\\Desktop\\xxx\\sources.txt" + "\n";
      ytSource += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n";
      ytSource += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE "+link+"" + "\n";
      ytSource += "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n";
      ytSource += "SET !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}" + "\n";
      iimPlay(ytSource);
      var source = iimGetLastExtract(0);
      var openTab = "CODE:";
      openTab += "TAB OPEN" + "\n";
      openTab += "TAB T="+link+"" + "\n";
      openTab += "URL GOTO="+source+"" + "\n";
      openTab += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n";
      openTab += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON:SUBMIT ATTR=CLASS:ytp-play-button<SP>ytp-button" + "\n";
      openTab += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n";
      iimPlay(openTab);
   }
}
```

Comment: this hurts my eyes

Comment: @DaniGuardiola I can not help it, the syntax of imacros requires writing in this way.